# Passing parameters to event handler in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send parameters to the on change event of a dropdown which is generated on runtime. How can i accomplish such thing like:

```
$(options.host_element).find('select').on('change',(graph_widget.draw_graph).bind(options));
```

options is the parameter i want to send to the function draw_graph, the function is linked but not the parameters

Comment: [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - check `data` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of your function's signature, but you can pass parameters to the function itself just like you do to any normal function, so it would look something like this:

```
$(options.host_element).find('select').on('change',function(){
    graph_widget.draw_graph(options);
});
```

Bind is used to change the value of `this` that will be used in the function, not quite what you're looking for.

I made a small fiddle to demonstrate:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrvjs4zx/)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.on` has an optional parameter called `data`:

```
$(options.host_element).find('select').on('change', options, graph_widget.draw_graph);
```

Later in your event handler, you may access data using `e.data`:

```
function draw_graph(e) {
   var options = e.data;
}
```